# multiply columns of seperate dataframes within factor (please take a look) R

Tags: r

```
v1 <- c("red", "a","b","c",1, 3, 5, 7)
v2 <- c("red", "a","b","c",1, 3, 5, 7)
v3 <- c("blue", "a","b","d",2, 4, 6, 8)
v4 <- c("blue", "a","b","d",2, 4, 6, 8)
v5 <- c("blue", "a","b","d",2, 4, 6, 8)

df1 <- data.frame(rbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5))

v6 <- c("red", 2,2,4,2)
v7 <- c("blue",1,1,0,1)

df2 <- data.frame(rbind(v6,v7))
colnames(df2) <- c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5")

> df1
         X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
    v1  red  a  b  c  1  3  5  7
    v2  red  a  b  c  1  3  5  7
    v3 blue  a  b  d  2  4  6  8
    v4 blue  a  b  d  2  4  6  8
    v5 blue  a  b  d  2  4  6  8




  > df2
     Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5
v6  red  2  2  4  2
v7 blue  1  1  0  1
```

How do I take the 4 numeric columns from df2 and multiply them within factor(red, blue) and within column (respectively)?  Say I would want to take (v6, X2) and multiply it by (v1:v2,X5).

If you need further clarification of what I am trying to do please ask.

edit:  For clarification, I want to make all possible multiplications of above example.

edit2: edited colnames

Comment: The fact that you have identical column names between two data frames but different variables in each will greatly complicate your problem.

Comment: column names are irrelevant.. use df1[,#] or change them if you want

Comment: No they're not, because you're going to need to merge the two data frames to do what you want efficiently.

Comment: @SeñorO, why not use `suffixes` in the merge?

Comment: colnames are edited.. sorry, I meant to say they are irrelevant as far as naming goes to both my example and my real data set.. I can change them as necessary.  My real issue is my weakness in coding.

Comment: Separate note, that is not how you build a data.frame. All items in `v1` (and other rows) are converted to characters. You end up with a data.frame where each column is a factor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, here are two possible solutions.  You can use `match`:

```
> df3<-df1
> df3[,5:8]<-df3[,5:8]*df2[match(df1[,1],df2[,1]),2:5]
> df3
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
v1  red  a  b  c  2  6 20 14
v2  red  a  b  c  2  6 20 14
v3 blue  a  b  d  2  4  0  8
v4 blue  a  b  d  2  4  0  8
v5 blue  a  b  d  2  4  0  8
```

Or you can use `merge`:

```
> df3<-merge(df1,df2,by=1)
> df3[,5:8]<-df3[,5:8]*df3[,9:12]
> df3[,1:8]
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1 blue  a  b  d  2  4  0  8
2 blue  a  b  d  2  4  0  8
3 blue  a  b  d  2  4  0  8
4  red  a  b  c  2  6 20 14
5  red  a  b  c  2  6 20 14
```